# Selecting and ordering by two fields

Tags: mysql

I have this query:

```
"SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY title ASC",
```

which works great.  However I've added in another field `tag` I now need to order by both tag and title.

Application wise this would be like having all your bookmarks grouped into tags (which are alphabetical), and finally with in each tag alphabetized individually.

I'm working on the code to to do this I just need the sql to give me the data in order.

If I had to guess:

```
"SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY title ASC AND ORDER BY tag ASC",
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You separate ordering columns with comma (check [*select clause* documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html)):

```
SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY tag, title;
```

`ASC` is not needed - it's the default sort order.

Comment: Wasn't your answer chosen? I think this problem has been solved.

Answer (score 3):

Since you want to group into tags, and then order by title, you have to order accordingly:

```
SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY tag ASC, title ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM bookmarks WHERE id=? ORDER BY tag ASC, title ASC;
```

Refer **[ORDER BY Optimization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/order-by-optimization.html)**

### SYNTAX:

```
SELECT * FROM t1
  ORDER BY key_part1,key_part2,... ;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1=constant
  ORDER BY key_part2;

SELECT * FROM t1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;

SELECT * FROM t1
  WHERE key_part1=1
  ORDER BY key_part1 DESC, key_part2 DESC;
```